# Use json.org on SoapUI groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to use org.json on groovy SoapUI to convert a JSON string into XML.

But When I'm trying to perform my groovy script (this one)

```
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.json.XML

    def str = "{'name':'JSON','integer':1,'double':2.0,'boolean':true,'nested':{'id':42},'array':[1,2,3]}";  
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
    String xml = XML.toString(json);
    log.info(xml)
```

I'm getting an error "unable to resolve class org.json.JSONObject , line 1, column 1.

I downloaded the jar on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20141113 , I put it on SoapUI/bin/ext but It's not working.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coping the `json-20141113.jar` in `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\ext` works for me, and your code executes correctly, logging this:

```
Thu Feb 12 21:58:53 CET 2015:INFO:<boolean>true</boolean><array>1</array><array>2</array><array>3</array><double>2.0</double><name>JSON</name><integer>1</integer><nested><id>42</id></nested>
```

Note that in order to load the libraries you must restart `SOAPUI`, maybe this is causing your error.

Note also that the `jar` you linked is compiled with `java 1.8` so check if you run `SOAPUI` using this version of java if not then you will receive `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` error. I say this because `SOAPUI` is available to download with or without java; if you download it with java the version is `java 1.7`. If this is the case you must download `java 1.8` and modify `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\soapui.bat` to use the correct version.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you mate, I also finally got it to work by using 

@Grapes(
 @Grab(group='org.json', module='json', version='20141113')
)
import org.json.XML;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;